# What is this geometry question saying?

Tags: geometry

**Problem**:
[image]

A few questions: what parallelogram is the solution talking about? Also how is its height $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and base $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2(1+\sqrt{2})}$?

Also, here is what I think the solution is talking about the parellograms (try calculating the height and you will see it is not $\dfrac{1}{2}$).

[image]

Comment: If you connect the opposite vertices of the squares, you will get four "pizza slices" which makes up one semicircle, and I suppose the rest can be split into parallelograms or triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the four rounded sections? If you move the lower two of them (by reflecting them over the $x$-axis, say), you can form the semicircle to which the solution is referring.

Separate that from the rest, and see if you can form four congruent parallelograms from the rest with some cutting and pasting, each having height $\frac12.$

**Edit**: Using your approach, you will construct $4$ parallelograms, each of height $\frac{\sqrt2-1}2$ and base $\frac{\sqrt2}2.$ Noting that $$\sqrt2-1=\frac{(\sqrt2-1)(1+\sqrt2)}{1+\sqrt2}=\frac1{1+\sqrt2},$$ we readily see that the area of these parallelograms is the same as that of those that were described in the solution.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that I am not getting their heights to be $1/2$.

Comment: What heights *are* you getting?

Comment: Do you see my picture? I am getting $\sin(22.5^{\circ})*\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Play with them a bit more. You'll see where the parallelograms of height $\frac12$ come from. Still, your approach is perfectly viable.

Comment: Can you tell me where those parallelograms with height $\dfrac{1}{2}$ are?

Comment: There are exactly three ways to put together that pair of triangles from your diagram to form a parallelogram. One way is yours. Another way yields a parallelogram distinct from yours, but with the same base and height. The third way is the one with height $\frac12.$

Comment: Remember: "base" doesn't mean it has to be on the bottom or top, and "height" doesn't mean it has to be a top-to-bottom measure.

Comment: You can also form a rectangle with a bit more cutting and pasting, but there's only one obvious way to do that.

Comment: As a final hint: the shortest side of the white triangle you've sketched is of length $\frac{\sqrt2}{2(1+\sqrt2)}.$

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome!